# Creating a rotating unit with the extended arms varying the trajectory in accordance to ODE's

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, materials, experimental-physics

I plan to mimic binary stars and their orbital decay due to gravitational wave radiation. I want to make a rotating shaft with extended arms, each being able to hold cast iron balls of specific weight, hence mimicking a binary with a circular orbit, when rotated.

This I can construct, my problem however is that I need the extended arms to vary in length such that they trace an ellipse with a specific semi-major axis and eccentricity. The arm must continue to vary in both of these parameters according to the ODE's which explain the time dependency as follows:

> $$\frac{de}{dt}=-\frac{304}{15}\frac{G^{3}m_{1}m_{2}(m_{1}+m_{2})}{c^{5}a^{4}(1-e^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}\left[1+\frac{121}{304}e^{2}\right]$$
>   $$\frac{da}{dt}=-\frac{64}{5}\frac{G^{3}m_{1}m_{2}(m_{1}+m_{2})}{c^{5}a^{4}(1-e^{2})^{2}}\left[1+\frac{73}{24}e^{2}+\frac{37}{96}e^{4}\right]$$
>   Note: The value of 'c' and 'G' I would be taking are  1 and 2.226e-19, to simplify the calculations.

I would then measure the time taken via a sensor, this would be the life time of the binary.

How do I build such a device? Is there any specific tech available that I can use for this specific issue that I have highlighted? Or can anyone provide some idea how to go ahead. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting or shopping question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: I'm just asking if such a rotational device can be made such that the trajectory the arms follow are ellipses with eccentricity approaching one with time.